# rotating around a point in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I want to make a object rotating around origin.

Following is a code:

```
Rotate(-360*Math.sin(time), 0.0, 1.0, 0.0); // rotate around y-axis
Translate(3.0, 2.0, 0);
renderSphere();
```

But when it starts, it first rotates from 0 to +360 degrees correctly, then it doesn't continue to go, but go oppositely from +360 to -360 degrees..

How can I fix this so that it just keep rotating correctly rather than going back?

Comment: Why do you use `sin` there? Sin is a wave, it goes back and forth.

Comment: Indeed. Try (time % 360) instead, but does your rotate function really work in degrees? Radians is far more normal for this. In that case, you'd want (time % (Math.PI * 2)) I believe.